# Calculate $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x-\log(\cosh(x))$ for

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I need help with calculating the following limit: $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x-\log(\cosh(x))$

So far, I've figures that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}x-\log(\cosh(x))=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(x-\log(e^x-e^{-x}))+\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\log(2)$

I've tried to rewrite algebraically back and forth, but I'm stuck in trying to reduce it to something I recognize the limits of. A hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: How is n and x conntected?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, I meant of course x instead of n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$x - \log\left(e^x - e^{-x}\right) = \log\left(\frac{e^x}{e^x - e^{-x}}\right) = \log\left(\frac{1}{1 - e^{-2x}}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** write as$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\log(\exp(x-\log(\cos h x)))=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\log \bigg(\frac{e^x}{\cos h x}\bigg)=\dots$$

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there

\begin{array}{rcl}
\ln(2) + \lim_{x \to \infty} \ x-\ln(e^x-e^{-x}) &=& \ln(2) + \lim_{x\to \infty} \ x-\ln(\ e^x\cdot(1-e^{-2x})\ ) \\
&=& \ln(2) + \lim_{x\to \infty} x-x + \ln(1-e^{-2x}) \\
&=& \ln(2)
\end{array}